# Maven error when compiling source file into jars

Tags: java, apache, maven, netbeans

I am trying to load miglayout into my IDE (netbeans) and then create a jar file from it. I got the source files for miglayout from https://github.com/mikaelgrev/miglayout and when ever I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8:jar (attach-javadocs) on project miglayout-core: MavenReportException: Error while creating archive:
Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - invalid flag: -Xdoclint:none

Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @packages

Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'C:\Users\mashraf\Documents\New Folder\miglayout-master\core\target\apidocs' dir.
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
  mvn <goals> -rf :miglayout-core
```

Does anyone know how to fix this, or what is causing the problem?